# Could not cast value of type A to type A

Tags: swift, xcode

I am relatively new to iOS development and swift. To get my feet wet I am working on adding some simple [Snapshot](https://github.com/uber/ios-snapshot-test-case) tests.

The tests themselves are really simple (more complicated are just mocking data for view controllers) and just need to create a View controller instance from the storyboard for the views I care about snapshotting.

```
func testJobAlertsSignupWidget(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SearchOverlayViewController", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SearchOverlayViewController") as! SearchOverlayViewController
    FBSnapshotVerifyView(viewController.view)
}
```

But I keep getting `Signal SIGABRT` exception right on the line where I do the cast `as! SearchOverlayViewController`. Additionally, I see this in the application logs.

```
Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.SearchOverlayViewController' (0x108655258) to 'MyApp.SearchOverlayViewController' (0x12d4a8058).
```

This line confuses me in all sorts of ways. The fishy part is the address is different on both references to type `MyApp.SearchOverlayViewController`.  If I remove the cast and use my debugger I can see that the viewController is the expected type. However the cast always fails.

Is my project building improperly so that something is being mis-linked or double-linked? I've deleted DerivedData and ran clean/build a few times to no avail.

The only thing close I found was this [tweet](https://twitter.com/Javi/status/641744126631763968) from a few years ago, but in that one their addresses are the same for both objects.

Comment: I always discourage the use of force casting (`as!`) because it causes crashes. In this case it seems like `storyboard.instantiateViewController` is returning something that's not the type you are force casting to. Verify that you set the correct class in the storyboard. If it's set correctly, when it crashes try `po storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SearchOverlayViewController")` in the console and see what it returns.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did check, it is definitely the correct type for both the storyboard and the viewcontroller. The actual viewcontroller code has a method which creates a view controller the same way I do and it definitely works when the app compiles with out issue.